# Adding unique ID to calculate duration of the status per status and ID but with multiple duplicate statuses occurring during the day

Tags: sql, timestamp, databricks, uniqueidentifier, duration

I have a table with multiple IDs and multiple statuses with timestamps. I need to calculate the duration of the status per status and ID so then I can select max duration of the status.
I have created end_timestamp so I can calculate the duration of each timestamp, but cannot get to the duration of the status. The example table below:

| id | status | timestamp | end_timestamp | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 10:20:45 | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 10/02/2023 10:50:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:50:45 | 10/02/2023 10:55:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | waiting | 10/02/2023 10:55:45 | 10/02/2023 11:00:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | waiting | 10/02/2023 11:00:45 | 10/02/2023 11:05:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 11:05:45 | 10/02/2023 11:10:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 11:10:45 | 10/02/2023 11:15:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 11:15:45 | 10/02/2023 11:20:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:20:45 | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | waiting | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | waiting | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 10/02/2023 10:50:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 11/02/2023 08:30:45 | 11/02/2023 08:35:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 11/02/2023 08:35:45 | 11/02/2023 08:40:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | waiting | 11/02/2023 08:40:45 | 11/02/2023 08:45:45 | 00:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 11/02/2023 08:45:45 | 11/02/2023 08:50:45 | 00:05:00 |

I have tried min and max but the problem is there are duplicate statuses per ID and per day. I have tried row_number with partition by id and status but it also did not work with so many multiple ids and statuses. I believe I need unique ID to be able to calculate the duration of each status per ID so then I can identify the max duration of each unique ID. Table I expect to have below:

| id | status | timestamp | end_timestamp | Duration | Unique ID | Duration per Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 10:20:45 | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 00:05:00 | 1 | 0:15:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 00:05:00 | 1 | 0:15:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 00:05:00 | 1 | 0:15:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 00:05:00 | 2 | 0:20:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 00:05:00 | 2 | 0:20:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 10/02/2023 10:50:45 | 00:05:00 | 2 | 0:20:00 |
| 1 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:50:45 | 10/02/2023 10:55:45 | 00:05:00 | 2 | 0:20:00 |
| 1 | waiting | 10/02/2023 10:55:45 | 10/02/2023 11:00:45 | 00:05:00 | 3 | 0:10:00 |
| 1 | waiting | 10/02/2023 11:00:45 | 10/02/2023 11:05:45 | 00:05:00 | 3 | 0:10:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 11:05:45 | 10/02/2023 11:10:45 | 00:05:00 | 4 | 0:15:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 11:10:45 | 10/02/2023 11:15:45 | 00:05:00 | 4 | 0:15:00 |
| 1 | available | 10/02/2023 11:15:45 | 10/02/2023 11:20:45 | 00:05:00 | 4 | 0:15:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:20:45 | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 00:05:00 | 5 | 0:15:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:25:45 | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 00:05:00 | 5 | 0:15:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:30:45 | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 00:05:00 | 5 | 0:15:00 |
| 2 | waiting | 10/02/2023 10:35:45 | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 00:05:00 | 6 | 0:10:00 |
| 2 | waiting | 10/02/2023 10:40:45 | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 00:05:00 | 6 | 0:10:00 |
| 2 | unavailable | 10/02/2023 10:45:45 | 10/02/2023 10:50:45 | 00:05:00 | 7 | 0:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 11/02/2023 08:30:45 | 11/02/2023 08:35:45 | 00:05:00 | 8 | 0:10:00 |
| 1 | available | 11/02/2023 08:35:45 | 11/02/2023 08:40:45 | 00:05:00 | 8 | 0:10:00 |
| 1 | waiting | 11/02/2023 08:40:45 | 11/02/2023 08:45:45 | 00:05:00 | 9 | 0:05:00 |
| 1 | available | 11/02/2023 08:45:45 | 11/02/2023 08:50:45 | 00:05:00 | 10 | 0:05:00 |

Comment: Please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text.

Comment: @NickW thank you for highlighting the issue. I hope current format is more clear.

Comment: I do not understand well what you want /I need to calculate the duration of the status per status and ID so then I can select max duration of the status/. Maybe it is a good idea to show the result you expect for these data from your query with an explanation?

Comment: @Catweazle thank you for looking into this. I think one of the great skills is to explain well what is expected, sorry for not being clear enough. I think in short I need to find an unique id for each status duration in sequence. As it is in 2nd table. So, if I have ID 1 'with 'available' status starting at 10/02/2023 10:20:45, it needs the same unique ID until the status changes. The problem is there is no specific number of timestamps per status and there might be multiple IDs with the same timestamp. I am not sure if that clarifies or complicates even more, but thank you in advance for help